# Puppet - MD5 sum of string

Tags: puppet, md5

I would like to name a file based on a MD5 sum of certain characters. Such as $environment and $URL. So from a high-level what I'd want is something like md5("http://$environment/$url").

Does anyone know how I get make this happen? Is there a built in function like Crypt::MD5 that I can use? Or should I write a custom function for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not fixed on MD5 hashes, you could use the [sha1 function](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#sha1). Otherwise you have to write your own function or you use the Ruby manifests (rather than the Puppet DSL) which are supported since Puppet 2.6.0.

Comment: Info about why you might want to reconsider MD5 as a checksum:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#History_and_cryptanalysis. Seems the prevailing opinion of those who know is don't implement anything new using MD5.

Answer (score 1):

As per what  @tore said, it is actually not that hard to write these little functions and extend Puppet DSL a little.

If you still need this MD5 and/or SHA1 check sum generation functions, then you can have a look at what I was able to do so far: https://github.com/kwilczynski/puppet-functions

I hope you will find some of these functions handy :)

KW

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be to difficult to create your own function:
lib/puppet/parser/functions/sha1.rb

This files contains the function for sha1 which can be used in Puppet DSL. If you know a little programming, maybe you can submit a patch to the Puppet team to add support for MD5 ?

Comment: Indeed I've just submitted a patch for this, it is really simple to add but may not be a good idea given SHA1 is a better algorithm.